# Remove application data while updating

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is there any tag in manifest/gradle to remove all application data while installing a new version of the app on devices.

As you know, while installing a new version of an application, Android os wants you to choose News or All(install just new contents or remove all data and install it).

is there any way to force to remove all data, and install the application?

**UPDATE**

I don't want to clear sharedPref manually and check version code in code.

My question is: is there any tag in the manifest or any way to remove all data automatically while installing the new version of the application on the device.

Answer (score 0):

**To know when your app updated**: just check your current app version.

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = activity.getPackageManager()
    .getPackageInfo(activity.getPackageName(), 0);
int versionCode = packageInfo.versionCode;
```

When your app starts, you check your `SharedPreferences` for an integer value with the version code. If there is none, or if it doesn't match -> your app is new or just updated -> clear data. Then, write the new `versionCode` value to the `SharedPreferences`.

**To clear your app data**: there's a new API introduced in API 19 (KitKat): [ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#clearApplicationUserData()).

```
if (VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= VERSION.SDK_INT) {
    ((ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .clearApplicationUserData(); // note: it has a return value!
} else {
    // use old hacky way, which can be removed
    // once minSdkVersion goes above 19 in a few years.
}
```

**Update**: SharedPreferences can be wiped in somecases.

To get app updating event 2nd way, using `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public YourUpgradeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Uri packageName = intent.getData();
        if(packageName.toString().equals("package:" + context.getPackageName()){
            //Application was upgraded
        }
    } 
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".YourUpgradeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: SharedPreference may get cleared if user manually clears app data without even installing new

Comment: @Stallion I've updated my answer, using BroadcastReceiver

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is stored in the app's `SharedPreferences`, you could use the `SharedPreferences.Editor` method `clear()` to delete all the app related data.

This way:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); 
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank for your reply